# Finding the conserved current of a scaling transformation

Tags: field-theory

I'm trying to find the expression of the conserved current associated with a scaling transformation. The Lagrangian density I'm working with is

$$ \mathcal L = {1 \over 2} \partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi -\lambda\phi^4, $$

and the transformation is

$$ \phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x)= \alpha \phi (\alpha x) $$

(here $x$ is a four-vector). After doing a few calculations I've found that up to first order in $\alpha$,

$$ \phi'(x)- \phi (x)=(\alpha-1) \Big[\phi(x)+x^\mu \partial_\mu \phi(x) \Big] $$

Taking the partial derivative with respect to $\alpha$ yields

$$ \delta_{\alpha}\phi=\phi+x^\mu \partial_\mu \phi $$

The lagrangian will transform in the same way, so

$$ \delta_{\alpha} \mathcal L=\mathcal L + x^\mu \partial_\mu \mathcal L,$$

and now I need to find $f^\mu$ such that $\delta_{\alpha} \mathcal L=\partial_\mu f^\mu$. But I'm having no luck. After digging around for a little bit I found out that this exact problem is featured in wikipedia's [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#Example_3:_Conformal_transformation) for Noether's theorem. However, there seems to be a mistake in the solution (or I'm just missing something), because they claim that $f^\mu=x^\mu \mathcal L$, and then

$$\partial_\mu f^\mu=(\partial_\mu x^\mu) \mathcal L +x^\mu \partial_\mu \mathcal L= 4 \mathcal L + x^\mu \partial_\mu \mathcal L,$$

which is not what it should be. I've gone through the sources on that article and cannot find where this solution comes from. I'd appreciate some help in finding that $f^\mu$.

I've also found the same solution (save for a sign) in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/522152/noethers-current-for-dilation-transformation) question here but they don't show the calculations, and again, either it is wrong or I'm missing something.

Comment: The mistake is in "the lagrangian will transform in the same way".

Comment: Really? In the wikipedia page they assume that, yet they reach that solution anyways, which leads me to think the mistake is somewhere else

Comment: No, Wikipedia says the conformal weight should be put in. These are not the same for $\phi$ and $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: Oooh, you are correct. When properly transforming the Lagrangian one obtains the correct result. Thank you.